# monochrome black-and-white bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap, monochrome

I'm working on Android for converting a colored bitmap captured from the camera into a black-and-white monochromatic image (no grays!).

I've got several methods for the gray scale conversion but I can't manage to get my image to a b&W format.

Are there any methods for converting a bitmap into this format?

Answer (score 2):

One solid way is a mean threshold bitmap. The method is described in [this paper](http://www.anyhere.com/gward/papers/jgtpap2.pdf), in the method section. It's often used for image alignment, and will compensate for different brightness levels, etc. You can use it straight from color, or after a greyscale conversion. After you get your image, you can simply set the white pixels to white, and black to black with `setPixels()` from a buffer.

You can also tweak it so that it doesn't use the mean exactly. You could have a slider for 0-100% black, where the mean would be 50%. That way you could do on-the-fly adjustments for each individual picture. You just have to recalculate the threshold and apply the pixel buffer again.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approatch:

1. getPixels() from Bitmap instance
2. iterate through all pixcels and if its code is more than some value to set white color otherwise black color.
3. setPixels() to Bitmap.

Comment: Thanks, but the big issue i have is that i'm taking pictures of a display that has got a lot of shadows and light...that changes a lot the visualization in black-and-white each time! any suggestion to this issue?